# initialize Class and list

Tags: c++, list, class, private-members

I state to be a beginner in C++.
This is the first time I use classes and I think I made a mess with pointers.
Until today I've always used the struct but with the private members I went haywire.

I need to create:

```
class Army{
private:
    WarriorEl* lista;
    int lungh = 0;
public:
    Army();
    ....other methods.....
};

class WarriorEl{
private:
    Warrior war;
    WarriorEl* pun;
public:
    WarriorEl();
    WarriorEl(int health, int mana, int index, float experience);
    ....other methods.....
};

class Warrior{
private:
    int health;
    int mana;
    int index;
    float experience;
public:
    Warrior();
    Warrior(int health, int mana, int index, float experience);
    ....other methods.....
};
```

In compilation it's fine, but when I run the code it crashes when variables are initialized.

main: http://codepad.org/Hm5mhsJv

Army.h http://codepad.org/AHM0OTxQ

Army.cpp http://codepad.org/Uuql3Wud

WarriorEl.h http://codepad.org/o3Q1V3Gf

WarriorEl.cpp http://codepad.org/AumIpNdo

Warrior.h http://codepad.org/x52A66fF

Warrior.cpp http://codepad.org/F5QZxnH9

Comment: How does it crash?  What error do you get?

Comment: First thing that's obvious: you're dealing with raw pointers, but are not declaring copy constructors, destructors or assignment operators. If you're going to manually manage memory via raw pointers, these are a must.  You also don't show the implementation of the constructors and the initialization of the pointers; they could be default initialized, which in C++ for raw pointers means they have random, undefined values. (No, I did not click the links).

Comment: The error is:
"An unhandled exception in 0x00A32AE6 in AIV11_WarriorConClassi.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000010."

@nathan so what should I do? From what I understand I've to write the constructor for each class, however, I thought I already did it.

Answer (score 1):

This error is seen when we try to write into some unallocated space.

Please check you loops and the corner cases to confirm there is no out-of-bounds access.